# What is the meaning of, "hacer carrera de alguien"?

Tags: significado

I found within a level A2 Spanish novel:

> El padre del dueño estudió Medicina, pero su hermano, Anastasio, no
>   quiso estudiar. Él quiso ser marinero. El abuelo del dueño actual se
>   opuso pero **no hizo carrera de** su hijo menor.

What is the intent of **no hizo carrera de**? What is the equivalent of this in English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> #### [hacer carrera con, o de, alguien](https://dle.rae.es/carrera#4XHmHaQ)
>
> 1. locs. verbs. coloqs. Conseguir que haga algo de provecho o se comporte como es debido. U. m. con neg.

Comment: Within the context of the novel I'm reading, this definition seems to be the best fit. The novel implies that the father could not get his son to do the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, **“Hacer carrera de alguien”** means: **"Provide a profession to someone"**

“Hacer carrera de alguien” is one or another expression of the Spanish idiom to say:
  "Proveer una profession a alguien"

For example, the following 3 sentences can be interpreted to have the same meaning:
1. "A way of saying it",
2. "a way of expressing it"
3. "a style of writing"

Essentially, “Hacer carrera de alguien” means: "Provide a profession to someone"
It implies providing or facilitating for the education and expenses to obtaining a profession based on an university degree.